# Substituting one variable in multivariable integration

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I'm currently looking into the change of variables done when relating the Gamma function with the Beta function.

I'd like to know how this author determined the new limits of $u$ when the actual substitution was for $v\to s$

[image]
They introduced $s=u+v$, and seemed to only replace the $v$ variable, but the limits of $u$ were changed.

I've looked into Iverson bracket method but I couldn't get the result:

\begin{align}
[0<u<\infty][0<v<\infty]
&=[0<u<\infty][0<s-u<\infty]\\
&=[0<u<s-u<\infty]\\
&=\,?
\end{align}

I also know about the general method (Jacobian, etc.), but I'm interested in this particular line of calculation. Sorry for the unclear title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already deduced that the region of integration is 0 < u < \infty, u < s < \infty. Observe that an equivalent description is 0 < s < \infty, 0 < u < s. The following sketch should give you an idea why. The rest just follows by change of variables and Fubini.

plot: the shaded regions are the same:

[image]

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164